# Most reliable way to do ~200 ms work in Android onStop

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I see frequent posts stating that file writing should be done in a background thread, even when the app is shutting down (`onStop`) -- even if the work is critical to the app.

I'm puzzled by this. Surely `onStop` is the one UI call where Android *should*, perhaps *must*, be lenient in giving the app time to complete *critical* work.

I am concerned that performing *critical* work on a background thread, does not *inform* the OS that ***the work is critical***, and needs to be completed.

There are several related aspects to this:

----- What is bothering me; the reason I wrote this question -----

1. **Is it *reliable* to do critical work on a background thread, after allowing `onStop` to return?**  Doesn't the return of `onStop` signal to Android that the app has finished what is critical, and the app will function correctly when resumed ***even if android immediately kills it***?

**(In other words, seems to me the advice [to do that critical work in a background thread] is wrong. I'm trying to find *evidence* one way or the other. This is the why i wrote this question.)**

---

----- Existence of any evidence that favors the background approach? -----

2. *Evidence* that if I follow the advice, and do the work in a background thread, that Android takes the existence of that running thread into consideration, when deciding whether it is okay to kill the app. [If I were writing a mobile OS, I wouldn't give the existence of a background thread much weight. I suspect most complex apps have background threads still running.]
3. *Evidence* that it is bad to delay the return from `onStop` by up to 200 ms.

---

----- Or existence of any evidence that it is okay to do it in the foregrround? -----

4. Or conversely, *evidence* that doing it directly in the UI thread is okay *up to some reasonable time*, and *evidence* as to what time might be considered reasonable.

---

----- Or what do the big app writers do? -----

5. *Evidence* about what approach is used by highly-downloaded, high-profile apps. Do they stay on UI thread while writing to file in onStop, or do that in the background? Or do they use a Service to be 100% sure? [I figure Android is unlikely to be changed in a way that will screw those guys over, unless absolutely necessary.]

NOTE: I've seen lots of opinions. I don't need to hear any more opinions. Looking for *evidence*.

NOTE: I'm not interested in hearing advice to create some Service or other solution that Android will keep running. I'm not talking about work that is lengthy enough to justify that. I'm talking about garden-variety work that every significant app does, when it is informed that it is being terminated.

---

**UPDATE**: I appreciate the information in the two responses so far, but I feel that one essential point is being overlooked:

There is one crucial difference between `onStop` and all the other UI callbacks:

**When an app returns from onStop, the act of returning is a statement from the app to the OS that the app can now be safely killed.**  Right?  Isn't that the essence of onStop?

Therefore, it **logically follows** that an app **should not return from onStop until it has completed all critical work**.

(And yes, one should obviously design the app such that this completion of critical work can be done as quickly as possible. But lets not lose the main point here. If you return, you are telling the OS it can now safely kill you. If it actually does kill you immediately, and your app state is messed up because you did that work on a background thread that isn't finished, then your approach is flawed. Isn't it?  **I'm trying to see what is wrong in my analysis here...**)

---

**UPDATE #2**
In discussion with @CommonsWare (see comments under his answer), I have learned that **an IntentService accomplishes what I want, and does not require any additional permissions to be asked from user.**

**I was thinking of iOS**, which is very strict about background work. I believe any such scheme would require an additional app permission under iOS. I avoid additional app permissions, so as not to scare off any users.

So as an experienced iOS app developer, but a less-experienced Android developer, **the answer I didn't know I needed was:**

1. Unlike iOS, [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) can be used, **WITHOUT ADDING ANOTHER APP PERMISSION**, to do [background work](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) **that the OS will continue, even after an app's activity has been terminated.**

Because the IntentService will continue running, and is not expensive to start, and does not require an extra app permission, there is no "downside" to using IntentService to start background work, allowing onStop to return promptly, while ensuring that the critical work is done.

I have accepted CommonsWare's answer.

---

**Update #3** Per @zgc7009's question in a comment, and my responding comment, I should also ensure that all critical info is persistently stored at all times. See those comments for details of what was not stored, until onStop, that caused me to post this question. The advantage of that constantly up-to-date approach is that it helps even if the app crashes.

NOTE: It is still essential (for reliability) that the mechanism used to save critical info is guaranteed to complete even if the app is going away. [Or at least a "transaction guarantee" that the data won't be half-way altered.]
I will probably use IntentService as part of making that happen. (our data is serialized XML, so our code needs to run until it has finished serializing the critical data, and flushed and closed that local file.)

Comment: Just to clarify: how much time are we talking about roughly here for the garden-variety work? Up to 1s? More?

Comment: As the title says, ~200 ms.

Comment: Though if there is any evidence in the 200 ms - 500 ms range, that is also useful.  Beyond that, I figure one is interfering too noticeably with the user experience.

Comment: Can you please phrase a clear, answerable question?

Comment: Android will draw on screen every 16ms. So at 1000ms which is 1 sec, there should be atleast 60fps. When you skip 200ms that would mean that you only have 800ms for drawing and you skip 10fps for the drawing. it concludes that your app has less than 50fps for drawing.

Comment: @TimCastelijns - what is unclear to you?

Comment: @Enzokie - But does that matter, during onStop?  During `onPause` that would be bad, but what about `onStop`?

Comment: all of those lifecycle runs on the main thread therefore all the execution from each lifecycle can affect the framerate.

Comment: Do you consider guidelines from docs as evidence? https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: Yes, you said that already. you didn't answer my question: ***DOES THAT MATTER*** (during onStop).

Comment: "I see frequent posts stating that file writing should be done in a background thread even when the app is shutting down `onStop` ",  this is your evidence.

Comment: @masp - I am specifically interested in the failure of the docs I've seen to discuss the different nature of `onStop`, from an app writer's point of view. I am hoping that either Android is more lenient during `onStop`, so that critical work can finish.

Comment: What is unclear? I don't know, maybe that you stated some stuff but did not ask a question

Comment: I want to contribute to SO's documentation but I would need lots of time to do some failure test and benchmarking. Yes the Android docs is not that really intuitive but not the whole thing in general.

Comment: @TimCastelijns - broke into sections, with a question at top of each section.  And added new Question #1, which is the heart of what I am asking.

Comment: You should really think about restructuring your app. You should not be triggering critical functionality while the app is shutting down, particularly since you have little to no control over the actual shut down process.

Comment: @zgc7009 - We save critical info at every step that it is created, so that rarely is there work to do in OnStop. But we have a queue of data being uploaded to server. If the server is slow or unresponsive, we save that queue in onStop. The data is also saved locally, but regrettably without that queue, it isn't clear which updated data needs to be re-synced the next time app starts. Yes, that is a design flaw on our part. Fixing it would be a significant amount of work, hence the desire to determine what is reliable during onStop.

Comment: Understood, out of interest, what would it take to store the queue in a local db or something like that to manage the queue instead of having a it set as a variable (or however you are doing it now)? I hear `it would be a significant amount of work` but just not sure the ideas you have gone over.

Comment: @zgc7009 - thanks, that is a very good idea, and would be reliable even if the app crashed! I simply had not thought about it that way. I'm so used to a queue as transient information; am just now realizing it is essential persistent information in this case. By "redesign", I was thinking I had to add a flag to every local record (which are hand-serialized xml locally, so that's extra code in every record type), to mark whether it had been successfully uploaded. Making sure the queue is physically stored at all times might be much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> even when the app is shutting down (onStop)

`onStop()` is a method on `Activity`. It will be called when the activity is no longer visible. That may or may not have anything to do with whether the app is "shutting down". For example, transitioning from one activity to another triggers `onStop()`, as do configuration changes (by default).

> Surely onStop is the one UI call where Android should, perhaps must, be lenient in giving the app time to complete critical work.

It is not a question of "leniency". `onStop()` is called on the main application thread. Anything you do on the main application thread ties up that thread, preventing Android from doing other work on that thread. Since the UI is driven by the main application thread, your UI will be frozen during the period of time you are tying up the main application thread in `onStop()`.

Note that this is not unique to `onStop()`. *Any* place where you tie up the main application thread is a place where the UI is frozen. Android developers have adopted the term "jank" to specifically mean this behavior.

You may feel that 200ms of a frozen UI is perfectly acceptable. Other developers may not. Users may or may not.

> But does that matter, during onStop? During onPause that would be bad, but what about onStop?

In many cases, it does. Just because the `onStop()` activity is no longer in the foreground does not mean that *none* of your activities are in the foreground, unless you only have one activity and this isn't a configuration change.

> that Android takes the existence of that running thread into consideration, when deciding whether it is okay to kill the app

It doesn't, unless that thread is being managed by a `Service` (in which case, Android takes the `Service` into account, not a thread).

To turn the tables, I would be keenly interested in any *evidence* that you have that Android will terminate your process within ~200ms of `onStop()` being called. Otherwise, your thread will run to completion without issue.

> I am specifically interested in the failure of the docs I've seen to discuss the different nature of onStop

That is because `onStop()` is not different, in the eyes of everyone else. You are welcome to believe that it is different, but please do not expect everyone else to "retcon" what has already been written about Android app development to adjust to your worldview.

> Evidence that it is bad to delay the return from onStop by up to 200 ms.

"Bad" is a subjective description. What can be stated is:

- `onStop()` is called on the main application thread (to prove this, log the thread IDs)
- tying up the main application thread prevents other work from being done on that thread (fundamental to how threads operate)
- [Android aims to update the UI on a 60fps basis](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/performance.html), or ~16ms/frame
- ~200ms is ~12 frames at 60fps (long division)

> When an app returns from onStop, the act of returning is a statement from the app to the OS that the app can now be safely killed.

An "app" does not return from `onStop()`. `onStop()` is a method on `Activity`. An app may have zero, one, or several activities. `onStop()` is loosely related to the application moving to the background, but `onStop()` will be called in other situations as well, as noted previously in this answer.

> If you return, you are telling the OS it can now safely kill you

You are assuming that failing to return from `onStop()` would keep your process alive forever. `onStop()` is an advisory event, telling you "hey, your activity has moved to the background". How quickly you return from `onStop()` does not matter one iota to the OS process that is responsible for terminating processes to free up system RAM.

Comment: "To turn the tables, I would be keenly interested in any evidence that you have that Android will terminate your process within ~200ms of onStop() being called."  Understood - seems like many people are relying on it *not* being terminated. But this seems like a shaky reliance. Given that most apps do have critical work that needs to be completed during shutdown, is this non-promised observation all that we have to go on? if so, to me that is a significant hole in the handshaking between app and os.

Comment: Re your points under "Evidence that it is bad to delay the return from onStop by up to 200 ms." I see what you are saying. I conclude that what I *wish* Android had was a way to start a thread that was marked `critical`, and that Android would give me another callback before actually killing the app. So it would be possible to know with certainty whether or not the work was done. And Android would favor allowing that thread to complete. A service seems like massive overkill, but if that is the only way to be sure, then that's how it is.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: "A service seems like massive overkill" -- I fail to see why. Use `IntentService`. Put your critical logic in `onHandleIntent()`. The `IntentService` runs that on a background thread and automatically stops the service when `onHandleIntent()` ends (assuming the service was not started again while the work was going on). Again, I tend not to bother with this until the work is likely to crest the 1000ms mark, but if you want to use it for ~200ms work, feel free.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: "Given that most apps do have critical work that needs to be completed during shutdown" -- first, `onStop()` is not "shutdown". Second, few well-written apps have any work to be done during app shutdown, for the simple reason that app shutdown cannot be detected. Apps *may* have work to do in `onStop()` of some of their activities. How critical that work is depends on the app and the activity. And, if you need to keep your process around for a bit longer to ensure that you work gets done, that's what services are for, such as an `IntentService`.

Comment: While it is true that onStop is not shutdown, it is equally true that after onStop, there is no further guarantee that your app will ever be called again. For the purpose of data persistence, it is necessary to treat onStop as if it were shutdown. Agree/disagree?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: "it is equally true that after onStop, there is no further guarantee that your app will ever be called again" -- there is no guarantee that your app will be called with `onStop()`, either. This is particularly true on Android 7.0+ with multi-window. `onStop()` is a state advisory, nothing more.

Comment: That's not what the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) say. As of Honeycomb, an app is not considered killable until onStop. (Without this guarantee, it would be impossible for any app to be sure its persistent state was up to date.)

Comment: BTW, I've upvoted your comment suggesting that maybe a service is not massive overkill. I understand that is the ultimate way to get a guarantee from Android; thank you for pointing that out. However, that does require asking the user to grant another permission; that is why I consider it overkill.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: That portion of the documentation may be out of date with respect to multi-window. For example, if your activity is visible, but in another window the user revokes a runtime permission, your process is terminated. I did not specifically test whether `onStop()` gets called prior to process termination, though I doubt that it is. Similarly, if you crash, `onStop()` may not be called.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: "that does require asking the user to grant another permission" -- services do not require permissions. Stuff the service *does* may require permissions, but that would be true if that stuff were done somewhere other than a service.

Comment: [services do not require permissions] Ahh, that is a very important point. My failure to be aware of that has colored my thinking strongly!

Comment: `Other developers may not.` <_< That. I would probably give a good punch to a developer who wrote the code that blocks my UI thread for 200ms

Answer (score 3):

Whatever task we perform in Android we try to finish it in **16ms** IDEALLY.

Because target is to achieve 60fps and 1000ms/60 is ~16ms.

So if we want that no frame should be skipped while the main thread is running,
we should follow this strictly.

As for example: if you try to write `Thread.sleep(200);` in the main thread. Your logcat will output that 'x' amount of frames were skipped, and you might be doing too much work on the main thread.

EDIT: If for some reason, your **main** thread blocks for more than **5 seconds**, you will be hit by the infamous **ANR**(App Not Responding) warning!

Comment: Note that the framework calls callback methods a lot. If you take up 15ms in `onStop()`, you may still drop a frame, due to the combination of `onStop()` and other callback methods. My general advice is to keep all callback methods under 1ms, so it is unlikely that enough will be called in rapid succession to cause jank.

Comment: While this advice applies very highly to every UI callback *except* onStop, I still ask whether avoiding a single UI glitch as an app goes away, is truly more important to our users than having certainty that the app's data is not corrupted when they return. That's why I wonder whether it would be better to hold on to onStop a bit longer to give time for the critical work to complete.

Comment: .. why I say *except* onStop, is because more is at stake during onStop. The return from onStop is equivalent to telling OS "you can kill me safely now".

Comment: hmmm, if there is no other way left then you will have no option other than doing it in onStop. but you should first think of all the possibilities. e.g: if you are doing some non-UI related cleanup, you can start a service in onStop and finish the onStop ASAP.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: "The return from onStop is equivalent to telling OS "you can kill me safely now" -- not really.

Comment: @CommonsWare - can you elaborate?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: "can you elaborate?" -- `onStop()` has little to do with "kill me safely". `onStop()` is for an activity; "kill" is for a process.